# Is it good practice if container's size is validated and accessing an element under same conditional statement?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Which one of the following code is more preferable between two of them and why?

**1.**

```
std::stack<int>stk;

//Do something

if( stk.empty() == true || stk.top() < 10 )
{
    //Do something.
}
```

or

**2**

```
std::stack<int>stk;

//Do something

if( stk.empty() == true )
{
    //Do something.
}
else if( stk.top() < 10 )
{
    //Do something.
}
```

Comment: They have different meanings, so... depends on what your code needs to do.

Comment: first one have or operator. so it two part can be true a particular time. but second one cannot true both condition at one time. so cannot compare these two ways.There are given answer is different.

Comment: Well if the `Do something` is equivalent. Then the first one would be preferred. You should try to not repeat yourself.

Comment: Yes Do something is equivalent.

Comment: Note that `stack.empty()` returns `bool`; there’s no need for `== true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builtin operators `&&` and `||` perform short-circuit evaluation (do not evaluate the second operand if the result is known after evaluating the first). So, expression `stk.empty() || stk.top() < 10` is safe and good practice, `stk.top()` is only called if `stk.empty()` evaluates to `false`. In other words, the operators were designed to enable such usage.

Comment: This is a good explanation of what happens in example 1, but does not answer OP's question of which form of the code is better.

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on the use case. In the first code, you have an **OR** condition for empty stack and checking the value of element if an element exist. So, it's clear and you can proceed with the code.

In the 2nd code, you want to execute something different for both the conditions. Hence you have put the conditions in a if else loop.

Good practise comes into sense when you don't want your code to break or pass corner test cases.You might not wan't something in your code when the stack is empty.

```
std::stack<int>stk;

if(stk.top() < 10 )
{
   //Do something.
}
else if(stk.empty() == true)
{
  //Do something
}
```

This will generate run time error since the stack is empty but you are accessing top element before checking the stack empty condition.
[Snap of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSqQP.png)

I hope the answer makes it clear.

Comment: "This will generate segmentation fault since the stack is empty" that's not guaranteed, officially that code would just invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Have added the compilation error snap in the answer.

Comment: that's not a compilation error, it's a runtime error. And again, it's more or less meaningless, it's just one of an infinite number of possibilities as the behaviour is undefined, one of those possibilities is to run just fine, as seen [here](https://ideone.com/25HDJe).

Comment: I meant run time error. Yes, it's a possibility but would be better to avoid.